# How to use custom mails with nodemailer other than gmail?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am working in an micro service project or crm. For sending mail I am using nodemailer with service gmail which is only working with gmail emails. But I need to send mail from other emails such as .....@iteccounsel.com or ....@quadque.digital which is not working. Also I don't know how to set app passwords for these mails. Currently I am using the original password which I use to login. I tried to set app password but didn't find any settings for these mails. So what to change to make other mails work ?

**Nodemailer code :**

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: ".......@quadque.digital",
      pass: ".........",
    },
  });
```

Is there anything I need to change in my code ? And what should I use instead of gmail in service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `service` prop from your `nodemailer.createTransport`.

Add a prop named `host` and fill it with your custom smtp host.
Also, remember to change `secure` prop in case you change the port from 465.

Example:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'something.domain.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // Change it to false if you wanted another port than 465
    auth: {
      user: 'username@domain.com', // Your email address
      pass: 'password' // Your password
    }
  });
```

Finally, you can use the transporter to send mail.
I hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Where to find my custom smtp host ?

Comment: Sorry for late response,
For quadque.digital website, if you are it's owner you can do that stuff, if else, it's impossible.